# Unable to paste text into remote window in RDP session using Microsoft Remote Desktop

Tags: swift

I have an app created in Swift 5 that uses CGEvent to paste text into the focused window. It works perfectly except I can't get this to work into a remote window running on a Microsoft Remote Desktop.
I can still use Ctrl+V with the keyboard to paste into the remote window but when I try to do it through code, all I get is a "v" in the remote window (Using Notepad as an example).
I figured it was because I am using virtual CGEvent maskCommand but for testing, I tried using the maskControl but got the same thing.
The code is pretty basic;
At this point, the text is already on the pasteboard

```
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
            
            let event1 = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: 0x09, keyDown: true); // ctrl-v down
            event1?.flags = CGEventFlags.maskControl;
            event1?.post(tap: CGEventTapLocation.cghidEventTap);
            
            let event2 = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: 0x09, keyDown: false) // cmd-v up
            event2?.post(tap: CGEventTapLocation.cghidEventTap)
        }
```

I get the exact same result with the above as I did with my original code:

```
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
            
            let event1 = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: 0x09, keyDown: true); // ctrl-v down
            event1?.flags = CGEventFlags.maskCommand;
            event1?.post(tap: CGEventTapLocation.cghidEventTap);
            
            let event2 = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: 0x09, keyDown: false) // cmd-v up
            event2?.post(tap: CGEventTapLocation.cghidEventTap)
        }
```

Both of these produce a single v character in the remote window.

I'm going to keep trying things as maybe it is a timing thing but was wondering if anyone has had this issue and was able to work around it.
I'm using Swift 5 and the latest version of Microsoft Remote Desktop

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to use an Applescript in my code to get the keypress to work as I needed and it is working now. I also used this to address an issue with clipboard syncing in RDP not working while the RDP app has focus.
In case Applescript support ends, I did add a user setting to enable the "Applescript" paste mode based on information found in the apple developer forum: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/98830.

```
    var script: NSAppleScript = {
        let script = NSAppleScript(source: """
            on lazyPasteRDP()
                tell application "System Events"
                    set activeApp to name of first application process whose frontmost is true
                    if "Microsoft Remote Desktop" is in activeApp then
                        tell application "myApp"
                            activate
                        end tell
                        tell application "Microsoft Remote Desktop"
                            activate
                            delay 0.5
                            tell application "System Events" to keystroke "v" using control down
                        end tell
                    else
                        tell application "System Events" to keystroke "v" using command down
                    end if
                end tell
            end lazyPasteRDP
            """
        )!
        let success = script.compileAndReturnError(nil)
        assert(success)
        return script
    }()

    func lazyPasteToRDP() {
        // https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/98830
        print("In lazy RDP Paste")
        let parameters = NSAppleEventDescriptor.list()
        parameters.insert(NSAppleEventDescriptor(string: "RDP Paste Issue Script Should Have Run"), at: 0)

        let event = NSAppleEventDescriptor(
            eventClass: AEEventClass(kASAppleScriptSuite),
            eventID: AEEventID(kASSubroutineEvent),
            targetDescriptor: nil,
            returnID: AEReturnID(kAutoGenerateReturnID),
            transactionID: AETransactionID(kAnyTransactionID)
        )
        event.setDescriptor(NSAppleEventDescriptor(string: "lazyPasteRDP"), forKeyword: AEKeyword(keyASSubroutineName))
        event.setDescriptor(parameters, forKeyword: AEKeyword(keyDirectObject))

        var error: NSDictionary? = nil
        _ = self.script.executeAppleEvent(event, error: &error) as NSAppleEventDescriptor?
    }
```